# Model-Glue Beginner Question

Tags: coldfusion, model-glue

I have Model-Glue (& ColdSpring) running in my wwwroot under my project. The problem I have is when I broadcast a message to call a method in my Controller, what happens is another method of the same name in a different folder(different project) gets called. How do i prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your coldspring config, set the debug value to true; reload your app; look at the big table of stuff that gets spit out at the bottom of your page. That'll tell you what ModelGlue is doing. It's very helpful for diagnosing behavior such as you describe.

Comment: This seemed to work perfectly. I traced the problem and sovled it, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It may be caused by some copy and paste mistakes.

Do a search on the message you just broadcast, and see if there are more than 1 controllers handling/responding to the message.  Should be inside `<message-listener>...</message-listener>`.